# Mobile App text Link

Tags: mobile

how to give text link in mobile app? I want to give link to text "Please note this baggage Alert" How would user know that it is link.

Comment: Please provide more context.

Answer (score 1):

How do you know that anything is a link when you browse the web?

1. It has colour that helps it stand out from its surrounding elements.
2. It is underlined.
3. It acts as a call to action "Book now", "Add to basket", "Contact us" etc.
4. It has a pointer cursor when you hover over it.

Now, everything apart from 4. can easily be transferred to a mobile app. Follow those [generally accepted & default conventions](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp) and you will be fine.